# Cant retrieve data from an SQL database using PHP and session variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a website with the following code in the header - but the PHP echos in the body are returning anything:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

$user = $_SESSION['email'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM first_page_data WHERE email_address= '$user' ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row_buyerdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

The following returns nothing:

```
   <?php echo $row_buyerdetails['phone_number'] ?>
```

I know the session variable named 'email' is receiving a value from the previous page from the print_r function on line 3. Variable $user is also getting the correct email address.

The database is set up correctly (ive been able to access successfully in other ways, but im trying to modify it to access the data related to a particular email address as shown).

If somebody could point me in the right direction id apprectiate it! Also as a side, how would people suggest debugging PHP other than littering the code with echos and print_r functions? Is there even a way to put breakpoints in for example?

---

### EDITED FOR HELP IN THE ANSWER BELOW

As requested, this is the code with the alterations requested:

```
<?php
$hostname_first_data = "*****";
$database_first_data = "*****";
$username_first_data = "*****";
$password_first_data = "*****";
$first_data = mysql_pconnect($hostname_first_data, $username_first_data, $password_first_data) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

echo mysql_errno($first_data) . ": " . mysql_error($first_data). "\n";

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
$user = $_SESSION['email'];
echo $user;
$query = "SELECT * FROM first_page_data WHERE email_address= '$user' ";

$result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);

$row_buyerdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

print_r($row_buyerdetails);

?>
```

Comment: Could you provide the return value for: print_r($row_buyerdetails); ?

Comment: Also, have you checked that for that specific user the query returns something?

Comment: @codeblur tried that, nothing! :)

Comment: Well, if print_r($row_buyerdetails); doesn't return anything... There's something wrong with your query :)

Comment: the page before is where the data for that particular email address is entered and it shows in PHPmyadmin as a new row so im presuming that the query returns something, (doing an echo on $result gives Resource id #12 but as I mentioned in the original post I dont know how to debug PHP so I dont know how to check it returns correctly!

Comment: you sure the line `<?php echo $row_buyerdetails['phone_number'] ?>` is in the same script then the sql call? if you paste it directly after the `mysql_fetch_assoc` does it still not work? Also, header and body are html related words. What do you mean by `PHP echos in the body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you missing a [mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) call in your header or includes?

Try adding:

```
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";
```

$link being the resource you get from mysql_connect.

To debug PHP you have to install or activate an extension that is called [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and use a *nice* IDE like [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), then Bob's your uncle :)

You can also use the [Zend Debugger](http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Debugger-Installation-Guide.pdf) but I have limited experience with it.

You can (and should) also have full [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) on when you are developing. It would tell you for example that the mysql_* functions are deprecated.

If you do not want the errors to appear on your page, you can choose to write to a log file and keep a tail open on that file.

Update for code:

```
<?php
$hostname_first_data = "*****";
$database_first_data = "*****";
$username_first_data = "*****";
$password_first_data = "*****";

$first_data = mysql_pconnect($hostname_first_data, $username_first_data, $password_first_data) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database_first_data, $first_data);

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
$user = $_SESSION['email'];
echo $user;
$query = "SELECT * FROM first_page_data WHERE email_address= '$user' ";

$result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);

echo mysql_errno($first_data) . ": " . mysql_error($first_data). "\n";

$row_buyerdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

print_r($row_buyerdetails);

?>
```

Tell me what that version outputs...

Comment: sorry - thats in a separate file called using <?php require_once('Connections/first_data.php'); ?> This definitely works correctly, as the data submission form on the previous page puts data into the database using the same file

Comment: What does print_r($row_buyerdetails); outputs?

Comment: Can you try the mysql error functions added in the answer? Also can you rewrite your code to use the specific resource returned from mysql_connect? i.e. mysql_query($query, $link);

Comment: added to the original question - im ready for you to pick my programming 'skills' to pieces! :)

Comment: lol! Could you try my version? I moved the error reporting line to after the call to mysql_query.

Comment: oooo your getting somewhere!! 1046: No database selected!

Comment: to be put in like so: mysql_select_db($database_first_data, $first_data); ?

Comment: Yes. I would include it in your Connections/first_data.php if I were you - except if your app talks to several databases - but then do not use mysql_pconnect.

Comment: You should also upgrade your code to use the mysqli functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: well thats got rid of the no database selected error, but the echo relating to the $row_buyerdetails still arent producing anything... :(

Comment: Have you tried to run your query from PhpAdmin? By the way, PHPStorm also includes a database console + editor :)

Comment: Sorted! The email addresses (for some reason unknown to me!) are being stored in the database with single quotations around them. So when I was searching for an email address without them it obviously wouldnt find them! Now ive got to find out why its submitting them to the database with quotes around them! Thankyou so much for your help, id've been lost for days on that one!